# CSS / HTML - Can hyphenation be applied to <input type="submit" value?

Tags: html, css, hyphenation

I am using a form to send POST data, looking like a link, as i don't see another possibility in my case.

I can obviously style the submitt-button to look like a link, but hyphens- or word-break parameters just won't apply. Some submitbutton's value text is longer than the surrounding div container, so i need hyphenation.

I even tried to give the specific input elements an id or class, but still no effect with css.

Any ideas?

```css
#box_link
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: lime;
}

#box_link input[type=submit]
{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;

  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#hyphbutton
{
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}

#box_link input[type=submit]:hover
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_link">

<form action="alarmierungssoftware/anwendungsbeispiele" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="stiller_alarm" />
<input type="submit" id="hyphbutton" value="Stiller Alarm / Hilferuf" />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: "As said, any hyphens or word-break parameters won't apply." — There aren't any in the code you've supplied. Nor is there any HTML. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: "Some submitbutton's value text is longer than the surrounding div container" — Your example code is missing the div … and has a *very short* label. It would help if you presented your [mcve] as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: edited once more, including running code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<button>` element instead of an `<input>`. There's no need for hyphenation rules: You have no particually long words, the text can wrap on the spaces.

```css
#box_link
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: lime;
}

#box_link [type=submit]
{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#box_link [type=submit]:hover
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_link">

<form action="alarmierungssoftware/anwendungsbeispiele" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="stiller_alarm" />
<button type="submit" id="hyphbutton" value="Stiller Alarm / Hilferuf">Stiller Alarm / Hilferuf</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: <input> actually works too if you set `white-space:normal` on it; see my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin ! Works perfect. And thanks for the lesson on using codesnippets, will do that in future posts.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is add `white-space: normal;` to the button; otherwise it won't wrap at all.
And get rid of the `word-break: break-all;`, that will wrap too much.

And in order to make the automatic wrapping routines work, it's very important that the browser knows which language we're talking about, so it can decide which hyphenation rules to use.
The automatic hyphenation seems to work only in Mozilla and IE though, not in Chrome.

Oh, and never mind the image in my source.

```css
#box_link input[type=submit]
{
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal;
}

#box_link input[type=submit]:hover
{
  color: red;
}

#box_link input[type=submit]
{
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box_link" lang="de-DE">
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td><img src="https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.isa.org%2FuploadedImages%2FContent%2FStandards_and_Publications%2FISA_Publications%2FInTech_Magazine%2F2012%2FApril%2F2012-4-36-alarm.jpg&f=1" alt="Stiller Alarm / Hilferuf" /></td>
     <td>
        <form action="alarmierungssoftware/anwendungsbeispiele" method="POST">
          <input type="hidden" name="param" value="stiller_alarm" />
          <input type="submit" id="hyphbutton" value="Stiller Alarm / Hilferuf" />
        </form>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```css
#box_link
{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: lime;
}

#box_link input[type=submit]
{
  background-color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;

  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
   word-wrap:break-word;

}

#hyphbutton
{
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}

#box_link input[type=submit]:hover
{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="box_link">

<form action="alarmierungssoftware/anwendungsbeispiele" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="stiller_alarm" />
<input type="submit" id="hyphbutton" value="Stiller Alarm / Hilferuf" />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Pls elaborate your question. if your problem is hyphen i think it's already solve